# Android Studio - Button XML Design

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout

Hello Im trying now for a while to recreate one of the Buttons
in the Picture below here (The Button with the Text "Fridge")

My problem is how do I create a colored bottom line with XML ?

[image]

Thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need add `tabs`

you can add color to this line by use `app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/blu"`

```
 <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="310dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginStart="33dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/blu"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/blu"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyTabLayoutTextAppearance"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/blu">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="50sp"
                android:layout_height="35sp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:text="@string/fridge" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="50sp"
                android:layout_height="35sp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:text="@string/freezer" />


    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

I hope it will work with you